# Отобразить прозрачный статус-бар в full screen режиме

Tags: java, android, android-style

Есть приложение развёрнутое на весь экран с помощью:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Этот режим меня устраивает во всём, кроме *статус-бара*. Его нужно показать. При этом фон *статус-бара* должен быть *прозрачным*, чтобы не закрыть элемент поверх которого он будет показываться.

Собственно, какая задумка и что в итоге должно получиться. Элемент поверх которого *статус-бар* будет показываться - это *Toolbar*. Мне нужно каким-то образом его вогнать под *статус-бар*. Если с *прозрачностью* я ещё разобрался худо-бедно, то тут как быть не знаю.

Например, как это выглядит в самом *Android*:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, по сути, это full screen режим, только статус-бар видимый и прозрачный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

То есть, делаем *статус-бар* прозрачным и отказываемся от флага *FULLSCREEN* (вместо него нужно выставить *LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS*). В итоге получаем то, что нужно.